# Issue with Python .format()

Tags: python, formatting

Im using this to get the number of email messages in my inbox

```
print("There are: {0}" .format(myEmailInfo))
```

It works sort of but what it returns is

```
There Are (2,217715)
```

Any ideas why?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What does `myEmailInfo` look like?

Comment: Well, apparently myEmailInfo is a tuple. What output are you expecting?

Comment: This is obviously not happening, `'are:' != 'Are'` for starters

Comment: The most basic debugging steps will answer your question. Simply examine what `myEmailInfo` contains -- it apparently doesn't contain what you think it contains.

Comment: @Chris_Rands and `:` has disappeared in the result ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do some debug to understand what is `myEmailInfo`: it could be a tuple (as it is printed like one) or an object with a string representation being a tuple (i.e. method `__str__` returns a tuple).

To help you perform debug, I personally recommend some software like:

- **PyCharm** (https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm), which has a free "Community Edition"
- **Visual Code** (https://code.visualstudio.com) which is a free tool from Microsoft with a great community and amazing support of Python

They both include some easy-to-use debuggers and amazing code completion for Python.

That does not answer the question (because we cannot without knowing more about your code), but that will help find the issue.

Comment: Here's what I did, it works now:
n = myEmailInfo[0]
for i in range(n):
    for j in myEmailConnection.retr(i + 1)[1]:       
        msg = (email.message_from_bytes(j)) #now it works         
        print(msg.get_payload())